# How to store the data in the list without overwritten the data?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

I am working on the json array loops to output the data so I can store them in the `EmailAddressData` list.

I have got a problem with this line under the loops:

```
emailAddresses = new EmailAddressData(firstname + "", email + "", url);
```

It will overwritten the data each time I fetch it and store it. I dont know what other ways I could use to store the data.

It will only work if I use this:

```
EmailAddressData[] emailAddresses = {
    new EmailAddressData("mark", "example1@gmail.com", url),
    new EmailAddressData("chris", "chris0@gmail.com", url),
    new EmailAddressData("vik", "vikey1234@gmail.com", url)
};
```

Here is the code:

```
getContacts = extras.getString("getcontacts");

//loops for each array...
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getContacts);

    if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String firstname = json.getString("firstname");
            String lastname = json.getString("lastname");
            String email = json.getString("email");
            String url = json.getString("url");

            emailAddresses = new EmailAddressData(firstname + "", email + "", url);

        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the EmailAddressData class:

```
public class EmailAddressData {
    private String name;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String userProfileImgUrl;

    public EmailAddressData(String name, String address, String imgUrl) {
        this.name = name;
        emailAddress = address;
        userProfileImgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {

        return emailAddress;
    }

    public String getUserProfileImgUrl() {

        return userProfileImgUrl;
    }
}
```

Could you please show me an example of what is the proper way I could use to store the data into the `EmailAddressData` list?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of structure do you want to store these in?  An array?  A `List`?  A `Set`?

Comment: I think its a set but i am not sure. I am using `EmailAddressData` so you might know better than I do?

Comment: I am asking what you're going to put your `EmailAddressData` objects into.  Do you want an array of `EmailAddressData` objects?  Do you want a `List` of `EmailAddressData` objects?  Or do you want a `Set` of `EmailAddressData` objects?  Or something else entirely?   There's no way that I can know better than you do, what you want.

Comment: Oh, I want to store the strings in the `EmailAddressData`.

Comment: Yes, you're doing that already.  You've already written the code that puts the Strings into `EmailAddressData` objects.  But you're going to make lots of `EmailAddressData` objects, so you'll need some kind of structure to store them all in.  I would suggest using some kind of `List`.  But I don't know what your requirements are.

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake, what my requirement is that I store the Strings into the `list` of `EmailAddressData`.

Comment: So, you'll need to make a `List` first - something like `List<EmailAddressData> listOfEmails = new ArrayList<>();`.  Then whenever you create an `EmailAddressData` object, you'll call `listOfEmails.add( ... );`, passing the object you created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly. Declare a list and store all objects inside it

```
getContacts = extras.getString("getcontacts");

List<EmailAddressData> list = new ArrayList<>();

//loops for each array...
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getContacts);

    if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String firstname = json.getString("firstname");
            String lastname = json.getString("lastname");
            String email = json.getString("email");
            String url = json.getString("url");

            emailAddresses = new EmailAddressData(firstname + " " + lastname, email, url);
            list.add(emailAddresses);

        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit: if you want to store them in an array, use this:

```
getContacts = extras.getString("getcontacts");

//loops for each array...
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getContacts);
     
    EmailAddressData[] array = new EmailAddressData[jsonArray.length()];

    if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String firstname = json.getString("firstname");
            String lastname = json.getString("lastname");
            String email = json.getString("email");
            String url = json.getString("url");

            array[i] = new EmailAddressData(firstname + " " + lastname, email, url);

        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the code you wrote `emailAddresses = new EmailAddressData(firstname + " " + lastname, email, url);` is incorrect. It will require me to replace it with `emailAddresses = new EmailAddressData[0];` so it is incorrect. The correct one is `emailAddresses = new EmailAddressData[]{
                            new EmailAddressData(firstname + " " + lastname, email, URL)
                    };` it works but it will overwritten the data in the `emailAddresses`. I want to store the list of strings in the `emailAddresses` list acting like an array. Any idea??

Comment: The correct one is `emailAddresses = new EmailAddressData(firstname + " " + lastname, email, URL); list.add(emailAddresses);` which it works but it will not store the data in the list as it will store the data at the end of the loops. I want to store all of the data in the list. Any idea??